# Swift show a different result with Objective-C in convert NSString to NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i use Objective-C to write some code which can help me to convert NSString to NSDate,but i find something interesting !!!

Here is my code:

```
NSString *string = @"周四 3月 24 14:44:00 +0800 2016";
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"CCT"];
fmt.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh"];
NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

and the result is

```
2016-03-24 06:44:00 +0000
```

but i use swift to write the same thing

```
var string = "周四 3月 24 14:44:00 +0800 2016"
var fmt = NSDateFormatter();
fmt.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
fmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "CCT")
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"zh")
fmt.dateFromString(string);
```

and the result is

```
"Mar 24, 2016, 2:44 PM"
```

you can find that swift gives us a correct time, but Objective-C seems incorrect.

so, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Note that `06:44:00 +0000` and `14:44:00 +0800`. +08 and +00 that should give in fact be the same date. A `NSDate` doesn't have the obligation to show +08 or +00 (time zone) in it's description.

Comment: What did you log exactly in your Swift code? A `NSDate` is in fact, only a timeStamp. If you check the value of the `[date timeIntervalSince1970]`, it should have the same value. NSLog(@"%@", date") is just a representation.

Comment: Yeah, i think i understand what your mean and what should i do , really really thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this. You have a date formatter that you are using to convert a date string to an NSDate.

Then you need some method to display that date as a string. If you use NSLog to display a date, it gets converted to a string by calling the object's `description` method.

Don't do that. Instead, feed the resulting date through a date formatter's stringFromDate method.

So you could use:

```
NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"date = %@", [fmt stringFromDate: date];
```

or from Swift:

```
if let date = fmt.dateFromString(string)
{
  print("date = /(fmt.stringFromDate(date))"
}
```

That will give the same results in both - the original date string. Alternately you could create a separate output date formatter that uses a different locale and/or format string and use that to display your results.

### EDIT:

You can create a date formatter purely for debugging. Here's the Objective-C version:

```
- (NSDateFormatter *) debugDateFormatter;
{
  if (!_debugDateFormatter)
  {
    _debugDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    _debugDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    _debugDateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
  }
  return _debugDateFormatter;
  
}
```

Then you'd use:

```
NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"date = %@", [self.debugDateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
```

Or in Swift

```
class Foo: NSObject
{
  lazy var debugDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter =
  {
    () -> NSDateFormatter in
    let debugDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    debugDateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    debugDateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    return debugDateFormatter
  }()
  
  func showDate(date: NSDate)
  {
    print( "date = \(debugDateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))")
  }
}

let aFoo = Foo()

aFoo.showDate(NSDate())
```

(In the code above I created a class Foo simply as a place to define my lazy `NSDateFormatter` `debugDateFormatter`. Your lazy var debugDateFormatter would probably go in whatever class needs it.)

Answer (score 0):

Because your time zone is different in both

Comment: Really? Both of the timeZone is "CTT"

Comment: thank you for your remind,but i change all of them as CCT, and the result is same

Answer (score 0):

The results are actually the same. Only the output formatting is different.

Change the swift code at the end to get the same result (so both use NSDate's `description` method under the hood):

```
let date = fmt.dateFromString(string)!
print(date)
```

Comment: wow!  so what should i do with my code and how can i get the same time with the NSString ? i think i really don't know what to do  :-(

Comment: i think i know what you mean and i find the reason,Thank you!